# Json API Python Iteration issue

Tags: dataframe, api

I am trying to iterate through Freshservice API and I don't know how to get the json format within the file to be able to use read_json for pandas? I will not be able to share the API link nor do I think I need to since I can touch the API and access. It would

```
json_data = []
for page in range(1,11):
    Rest1 = requests.get(Change_URL_api + f"{page}",auth=HTTPBasicAuth('Username','Password'))
    new_results = json.loads(Rest1.text)
    json_data.append(new_results)

print(json_data)

with open('change.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data))

dataframe=pandas.read_json('change.json',orient='records')
```

Format within json file:

```
[{"changes": [{"agent_id": xxxxxx, "group_id": xxxxx, "priority": x, "impact": x, "status": x, "risk": x, "change_type": x,
```

This is the following format I see within the dataframe. I believe it has a different page for each index based off my range.

```
Index             Changes
0                  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
1                  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
```